# SFDX - deploy a brand new custom object with only specific fields from one org to another

Tags: salesforcedx, custom-object, deployment, custom-field

I have a scenario where I need to deploy a brand new custom object only with specific custom field(s) to another org. The other org does not have that custom object at all.

I'm using sfdx for VS Code to retrieve and deploy. It uses the `sfdx force:source:retrieve --manifest` and `sfdx force:source:deploy --manifest` command.

**Example :**

If I retrieve and deploy only the custom field, first it will only retrieve the custom field without the custom object file and when it tries to deploy it will give me error that custom object is not found in target org. Which makes sense.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Burger__c.Burger_Type__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <version>49.0</version>
</Package>
```

Output

```
=== Retrieved Source
FULL NAME                 TYPE         PROJECT PATH
────────────────────────  ───────────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Burger__c.Burger_Type__c  CustomField  force-app\main\default\objects\Burger__c\fields\Burger_Type__c.field-meta.xml
```

Error (when deploying)

```
Entity 'Burger__c' not found
```

But even if I retrieve and deploy like this, it ignores what ever custom field I mention. If custom object is listed it will retrieve and deploy most of everything of that object as seen in output below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Burger__c.Burger_Type__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Burger__c</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>49.0</version>
</Package>
```

Output

```
=== Deployed Source
STATE  FULL NAME                 TYPE          PROJECT PATH                                                                      
─────  ────────────────────────  ────────────  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Add    Burger__c.Burger_Type__c  CustomField   force-app\main\default\objects\Burger__c\fields\Burger_Type__c.field-meta.xml     
Add    Burger__c                 CustomObject  force-app\main\default\objects\Burger__c\Burger__c.object-meta.xml                
Add    Burger__c.Brand__c        CustomField   force-app\main\default\objects\Burger__c\fields\Brand__c.field-meta.xml           
Add    Burger__c.Callories       RecordType    force-app\main\default\objects\Burger__c\recordTypes\Callories.recordType-meta.xml
```

**Coming back to question :**

Is there any neat way to deploy a brand new object with specific components or fields from one org to another using sfdx. Or my scenario is not very common and not important ?

**SFDX INFO :**

```
sfdx-cli/7.82.0-3d0c527ac6 win32-x64 node-v12.18.3

@oclif/plugin-autocomplete 0.1.5 (core)
@oclif/plugin-commands 1.3.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-help 3.2.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-not-found 1.2.4 (core)
@oclif/plugin-plugins 1.9.4 (core)
@oclif/plugin-update 1.3.10 (core)
@oclif/plugin-warn-if-update-available 1.7.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-which 1.0.3 (core)
@salesforce/sfdx-trust 3.4.3 (core)
alias 1.1.3 (core)
analytics 1.12.1 (core)
auth 1.3.0 (core)
config 1.2.1 (core)
generator 1.1.3 (core)
salesforcedx 50.7.0 (core)
├─ schema 1.0.1 (core)
├─ templates 50.1.0 (core)
├─ @salesforce/sfdx-plugin-lwc-test 0.1.7 (core)
├─ salesforce-alm 50.7.0 (core)
├─ custom-metadata 1.0.10 (core)
└─ apex 0.1.4 (core)
sfdx-cli 7.82.0 (core)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could utilize .forceignore for this scenario

.forceignore

```
# Use with caution. Specify a relative path to a file from the project root. If you place a file in a forceignore, basically sfdx skips deploying this file. If your ready to commit them to another org. just remove this line from .forceignore file
force-app/main/default/objects/myObject/fields/SampleField__c.field-meta.xml
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm

Comment: that would be very much possible. Guess I need to write my own package and component tracking tool. I was expecting to rely on package.xml